# Unable to flush reusable UITableViewCell data

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView with a custom UITableViewCell.

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

//create the cell
MyCell *cell = (MyCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];
cell.label.text = ..
cell.label2.text = ..
cell.label3.text = ..
```

Everything works fine, all my data loads properly, etc.

Now, I have a button on this View Controller that opens another view where the user can select which labels to display.  So, for instance, display labels 1 and 3, but not 2...
Then, when `Done` is clicked, I want the tableView to be updated to reflect the new options, but since the cells were loaded with a reuseCellId, no changes are shown.  How can I force the cells to recreate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by just destroying the tableview, and recreating it every time.

Answer (score 0):

**This is NOT a good approach**
One way you can do this by using different identifier when you want to refresh cells

I am not sure if there is any other better way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I thing that the best thing you could do is to store the cells configuration in some kind of structure (a set with the labels indices to be shown would be ok here) and alter this structure with your buttons and reload the table view. Then, on your tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method, you should check that configuration structure in order to know what buttons should be visible.

This code may help:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController
{
    ...
    NSMutableSet *_labelsToShow;
}

...
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableSet labelsToShow

@end


@implementation MyViewController
@synthesize labelsToShow = _labelsToShow;

- (void)dealloc
{
    [_labelsToShow release];
    ...

}


//you may know which button has to add/remove each label, so this needs to be fixed with your logic
- (IBAction)myButtonAction:(id)sender
{
    if (hasToShowLabel)
    {
        [self.labelsToShow addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:labelIdentifier]];
    } else
    {
        [self.labelsToShow removeObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:labelIdentifier]];
    }
}

-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"myCell";
    MyCustomCell *cell = (MyCustomCell *)[tableView dequeReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[MyCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault] autorelease];
    }

    cell.label0.hidden = (![self.labelsToShow containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:0]]);
    cell.label1.hidden = (![self.labelsToShow containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:1]]);
    cell.label2.hidden = (![self.labelsToShow containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:2]]);
    ...

    return cell;
}


@end
```

Good luck with this!